# “circle” Cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method that reads a file and creates an object based on the information inside the file.

However, when I try to return the object, I get a "cannot be resolved to a variable" error.

```
    public static Circle readCircle(Scanner in) {

        while (in.hasNext()) {

            int px = in.nextInt();
            int py = in.nextInt();
            int vx = in.nextInt();
            int vy = in.nextInt();
            int diameter = in.nextInt();

            Circle circle = new Circle(px, py, vx, vy, diameter);

        }

        return circle; //Error is here.

    }
```

As far as I understand, this is a scope problem. I have tried to declare Circle as null before the while loop but to no effect.

Comment: “circle” is declared in, hence scoped to, the “while” block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring the circle variable before the loop should work in theory, but for this case I'd do something like this:

```
    if (in.hasNext()) {

        int px = in.nextInt();
        int py = in.nextInt();
        int vx = in.nextInt();
        int vy = in.nextInt();
        int diameter = in.nextInt();

        return new Circle(px, py, vx, vy, diameter);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
```